# What is equivalent of cts:element-query in MarkLogic Java API

Tags: java, xquery, marklogic

I have a MarkLogic query written in XQuery and I would like to convert it to Java API using `StructuredQueryBuilder`. Unfortunately, I can't find Java equivalent for `cts:element-query`. Can you please show me how to implement it in Java?

The query that I want to convert:

```
cts:element-query(fn:QName("http://www.example.com/2009/pfi2","content"), cts:word-query("florists", ("case-insensitive","lang=en"), 4.5), ())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`StructuredQueryBuilder.containerQuery()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/query/StructuredQueryBuilder.html#containerQuery-com.marklogic.client.query.StructuredQueryBuilder.ContainerIndex-com.marklogic.client.query.StructuredQueryDefinition-) method constructs a `search:container-query` in the Search API. On the enode, the REST API converts the `search:container-query` to `cts:element-query()` or `cts:json-property-query()` or `cts:json-property-scope-query()` as appropriate.

For more detail, see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/query/StructuredQueryBuilder.html#containerQuery-com.marklogic.client.query.StructuredQueryBuilder.ContainerIndex-com.marklogic.client.query.StructuredQueryDefinition-

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/structured-query#id_87231

The other way to provide the query in the Java API is to serialize the `cts:element-query()` as JSON or XML to learn the query structure and then use a DOM to construct the query and pass the query as a `RawCtsQueryDefinition` payload.

For that approach, see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches#id_45762

http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/query/RawCtsQueryDefinition.html

Hoping that helps,